# Why is form data not receiving the form fields using serializeArray()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, form-data

I don't know why the form fields aren't been extracted thru the `serializeAll()` function and not reaching the called php page.

```
print_r($_FILES)                 // brings me data.

print_r($_POST/$_REQUEST/$_GET)  // brings me NO data.
```

**HTML** form

```
<section id="featured">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form id="includeExamform" method="post" class="validateform" name="send-contact">
                <div class="title"><h3> <strong> CADASTRO EXAME </strong></h3></div>    
                    <div id="select-patient">
                        Paciente: <button class="btn btn-theme btn-search margintop10 pull-left" type="button" onCLick="popupCenter('selecionaPaciente.php', 'selecionaPaciente', 750, 500);" >Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>      
                    <br>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        Contactóloga: <input type="text" id="contactologa" size="50"  maxlength="50"  />
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        Deficiencia: <input type="text" id="deficiency" size="50" maxlength="50"   />
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <strong><font color="Black">Longe   </font></strong>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        D_Esf.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_D_Esf" size="5" maxlength="5" />     D_CIL.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_D_CIL" size="5" maxlength="5" />      D_Eixo a:<input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_D_Eixo" size="3" maxlength="3" />  
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        E_Esf.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_E_Esf" size="5" maxlength="5" />     E_CIL.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_E_CIL" size="5" maxlength="5" />      E_Eixo a:<input class="degree" type="text" id="longe_E_Eixo" size="3" maxlength="3" /> 
                    </div>
                    <br></br>
                    <strong><font color="Black">Perto</font></strong>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        D_Esf.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_D_Esf" size="5" maxlength="5" />     D_CIL.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_D_CIL" size="5" maxlength="5" />      D_Eixo a:<input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_D_Eixo" size="3" maxlength="3" />  
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="field-type-1">
                        E_Esf.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_E_Esf" size="5" maxlength="5" />     E_CIL.: <input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_E_CIL" size="5" maxlength="5" />      E_Eixo a:<input class="degree" type="text" id="perto_E_Eixo" size="3" maxlength="3" /> 
                    </div>
                    <br></br>               
                    <div class="field-type-1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input name="userfile" type="file" id="userfile" class="filestyle" data-classButton="btn btn-primary" data-input="false" data-classIcon="icon-plus" data-buttonText="Escolha um arquivo">       
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        Comentarios Adicionais: <textarea rows="7" id="remarks" class="input-block-level" placeholder="* Comentarios Adicionais..." ></textarea> 
                        <br></br>
                        <p>
                                <button class="btn btn-theme btn-register margintop10 pull-left" type="button" onclick="return inserirExame(0);">CADASTRAR</button>
                                <span class="pull-right margintop20">* Por favor preencha todos os campos, obrigado!</span>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

**JS/JQuery** *(data manipulation)*

```
var fd = new FormData();

var other_data = $('#includeExamform').serializeArray();
$.each(other_data,function(key,input){
    fd.append(input.name,input.value);
});

var file_data = $('input[type="file"]')[0].files; // for multiple files
for(var i = 0;i<file_data.length;i++){
    fd.append("file_"+i, file_data[i]);
}
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: caminho+"/view/cadastroExame.php?acao=salvar",
        timeout: 20000,
//      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data: fd,
        success: 
            function(data){
                if(jQuery.trim(data) == 'ok'){
                    alert('Sucess!');
                    $("#includeExamform")[0].reset();
                    $("#select-patient").html('Paciente: <button class="btn     btn-theme btn-search margintop10 pull-left" type="button" onCLick="popupCenter(\'selecionaPaciente.php\', \'selecionaPaciente\', 750, 500);" >Pesquisar</button>');
//                  window.location = caminho+"/view/cadastroFornecedor.php";
                }
                else{
                    alert('Exam already registered!');
                }
            }
    });
}
```

**PHP** *(test I'm performing and have no form-fields data)*

```
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_REQUEST);
print_r($_GET);

if ( 0 < $_FILES['file']['error'] ) {
   echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['file']['error'] . '<br>';
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'uploads/' . $_FILES['file']['name']);
}
```

**Web Browser Console** *(results)*

```
Array
(
    [file_0] => Array
        (
            [name] => PENDENCIAS IMA.txt
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /var/lib/openshift/5702831b7628e1462200001a/php/tmp/phpyvipCz
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 1270
        )

)
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [acao] => salvar
)
```

[image: Debugger Variable Content]

Comment: Any reason you don't just use `new FormData($("includeExamform")[0])`?

Comment: Check the Network tab to see what's being sent.

Comment: @Barmar As far as I know it's necessary to append field by field in order to be able to identify and retrieve information later in php code. Am I wrong?

Comment: If the argument to `new FormData()` is a form, it's automatically filled in with all the input fields in the form.

Comment: @Barmar Added console results in the post(I said it got empty). As you can see, only the File is been sent thru.

Comment: What does the Network tab in the browser's console show when you perform the AJAX request?

Comment: @Barmar Please look at Browser Console Results:

Comment: That's not the browser console results, that's the output from the script. I'm talking about going into Developer Tools, then going to the Network tab and looking at the request data.

Comment: @Barmar The request payload only contains the following information besides the file content: -----------------------------25051760818494
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_0"; filename="PENDENCIAS IMA.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Comment: @Barmar Also if you look at the debugger, it's clear the variable other_data is not been loaded with anything... Just put a printscreen above...

Comment: Seems just found the main issue... The HTML fields didn't have the "name" tag... I read many times that serializeArray() doesn't work if the HTML field does not have a name, but I was so addicted to my code(I was "certain" it has) that I just assumed everything was named. That is to remember: Never play smart when programming :)

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it. It's often something stupid like this.